# Why the Toggle buttons are flashing on reload?

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

When i **reload** my page, my **toggle-buttons** which are hidded by making `opacity-0` appears on flash. 
Is there any way to stop these flashes from appearing **on reload** and keep the (`opacity-0`) items **hidden** as intended?
[Live Site URL](https://mustakabsarkhan.github.io/Calculator-App/)
[Codebase-Github Repo](https://github.com/MustakAbsarKhan/Calculator-App)

```
//loads user preference after reload based on user's previous session
window.onload = () => {
  "toggle1" == localStorage.getItem("clicked")
    ? (toggleHide("toggle1"), theme1())
    : "toggle2" == localStorage.getItem("clicked")
    ? (toggleHide("toggle2"), theme2())
    : "toggle3" == localStorage.getItem("clicked")
    ? (toggleHide("toggle3"), theme3())
    : console.log("infinity");
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to make all three themes hidden by default and `onload` method, you decide which theme you want to show, and by default, if there no `clicked` item in the `localStorage` show the first theme, and this will prevent flashing.

```
window.onload = () => {
  "toggle1" == localStorage.getItem("clicked")
    ? (toggleHide("toggle1"), theme1())
    : "toggle2" == localStorage.getItem("clicked")
    ? (toggleHide("toggle2"), theme2())
    : "toggle3" == localStorage.getItem("clicked")
    ? (toggleHide("toggle3"), theme3())
    : (toggleHide("toggle1"), theme1())
};
```

Comment: This idea works. But to have it working for me, i did this little change to the code. I have added this extra portion to the last line. `: ((activeButton = "toggle1"), toggleHide("toggle1"), theme1());`